# Warum steht kein Komma vor „derart“ in Sätzen der Form „Es gibt ein x derart, dass …“?

Tags: conjunction, comma

Warum wird oft (fast immer) **kein** Komma vor *derart* in Sätzen der folgenden Form gesetzt?

> Es gibt ein *x* derart, dass …

Müsste es nicht eigentlich wie folgt heißen:

> Es gibt kein *x***,** derart, dass …

Comment: Servus und willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Es gibt eine [tour] dieser Seite. Fragen darüber, wie sie funktioniert, beantwortet dir das [help].

Comment: Danke. [das steht nur hier, damit ich genügend Zeichen in dem Kommentar habe, um ihn abzuschicken]

Comment: Ersetze *derart* durch ein funktionsgleiches *so* und plötzlich ist dein Wunsch nach dem Komma vollkommen verschwunden...

Answer (score 3):

In meinen Augen sind nur die beiden folgenden Interpretationsmöglichkeiten denkbar:

1. > Es gibt kein *x* derart, dass …

   Im Prinzip kann man das umkehren zu:

   > Es gibt kein derartiges *x*, sodass …

   Das *derart* gehört also zum vorigen Satz. Es mit einem Komma abzutrennen wäre merkwürdig.
2. > Es gibt kein *x*, derart dass …

   Hier wäre *derart dass* eine zweiteilige Konjunktion wie auch *ohne dass* oder Andere. Für diesen Fall schreiben die Rechtschreibregeln vor, dass das Komma vor der gesamten mehrteiligen Konjunktion zu stehen hat.

Comment: Was ist der Unterschied zwischen 1. und 2. von der Bedeutung her? Ich habe gelernt, dass man vor einem "dass" stets ein Komma setzen sollte. Wieso machst du dies bei 2. nicht?

Comment: @eueueu Die Regel ist zu stark vereinfacht: »Ja, ich bin gegangen, **ohne dass** ich dir das angekündigt habe.«

Comment: Im ersten Fall gehört *derart* zum ersten Satz, also eher zum *x*. Im zweiten Fall zum zweiten Satz, am ehesten zum *dass* dazu.

Comment: Was ist der Unterschied zwischen 1. und 2. *von der Bedeutung her*?

Comment: Der Unterschied ist bei unvollständigen Sätzen kaum zu nennen.

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort *derart* ist kein Adjektiv, das sich auf *ein x* bezieht, sondern ein Adverb (siehe [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/derart)), dass sich auf das Verb *gibt* bezieht. Wenn man den Satz umstellt, sieht man besser, weshalb da kein weiteres Komma stehen kann:

> Es gibt derart ein x, dass ...

Außerdem wird durch die Umstellung noch deutlicher, dass *dertart* die Art und Weise des Gebens bezeichnet, auf die sich der anschließende Nebensatz bezieht:

> Es gibt in der Art und Weise ein x, dass ...

Falls, einen passenden Kontext vorausgesetzt, doch ein Adjektiv gewünscht ist, das sich auf *ein x* bezieht, kann man *derartig* verwenden:

> Es gibt ein derartiges x, dass ...