# Komma vor „derart“ in bestimmten Sätzen

Tags: comma, subordinate-clause

Man betrachte folgenden Satz:

> Es gibt ein *x* derart, dass …

In diesem Satz wird vor *derart* **kein** Komma gesetzt.

Nun betrachte man aber Sätze der folgenden Form:

> Es gilt …, falls es ein *x* gibt**,** derart**,** dass …

Ist die Kommasetzung in diesem Satz richtig? Oder müsste man das Komma vor *derart* in diesem Satz weglassen?

Comment: Relevant aber mE nicht ganz ein Duplikat: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/30175

Comment: M.A. nach auch ein Duplikat, aber ein Tipp: Ersetze *derart* durch das (hier) gleichbedeutende *so* und versuche das mit dem Komma nochmal.

Comment: Lieber iiiiii, kennst Du eigentlich [eueueu](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30175/warum-steht-kein-komma-vor-derart-in-s%c3%a4tzen-der-form-es-gibt-ein-x-derart-da) und [eueueueueue](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30013/translation-of-such-that-so-dass)? Die beiden haben ähnlich komische Namen wie Du und stellen ganz ähnliche Fragen. Vielleicht könntet Ihr Euch ja einen Account teilen.

Comment: @iiiiiii Kannst Du den Satz mal bitte ausformulieren? Ich fürchte, da liegt eher ein Problem mit Satzbau und Stil vor als mit Kommas.

Comment: @Matthias Das scheint mir kein Deutsch, sondern Mathematisch zu sein. Da gehört das so.