# "derart, dass" in Mathematik

Tags: meaning, mathematics

While reading mathematics in German, I came upon the phrase "derart, dass." Does this mean something along the lines of "such that," and if so, does it differ from "so, dass?"

Comment: Please do not capitalise German words just because they appear in heading. Capitalisation has a grammatical function in German.

Comment: Related (but different): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30175/warum-steht-kein-komma-vor-derart-in-s%c3%a4tzen-der-form-es-gibt-ein-x-derart-da

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, "derart, dass" means the same as "so dass", namely "such that". "So, dass" is more common, though. There is also "dergestalt, dass", which means the same, but is even rarer.